# Como montar um combo dinâmico com angular 5?

Tags: angular

Estou tentando montar um combo dinâmico com Angular, porém não estou tendo sucesso, eu conseguir implementar com valores estáticos, mas não tive sucesso quando fui adaptar-lo com minha API Java que tem conexão com o banco de dados.

O meu objetivo é ao carregar um dropdown list de um estado do brasil ele possa carregar automaticamente o segundo dropdown list das cidades do brasil correspondente aquele estado do brasil que foi selecionado no primeiro dropdown list.

**OBS: os dados que estão no meu banco de dados local eu inserir as cidade e estados com insert no banco.**

Através do facebook encontrei esse exemplo de combo dinâmico com **dados estáticos** para entenderem o que preciso:

**O efeito prático está nos 21 minutos e 38 segundos desse vídeo.**

[Angular 5 - Select Dinâmico](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGI3Uu-ns4g&feature=youtu.be)

O exemplo com dados estáticos está tendo esse tipo de retorno;

```
 this.cidadesService.buscarEstados().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(this.estados = result);
    });
```

Ficou assim;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E com cidades ficou assim;

```
 buscarCidades() {
    this.cidadesService.buscarCidadePorUF(
      this.uf)
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log(this.estados = result);
      });
  }
```

Ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O repositório com dados estático dicou assim, [Clique Aqui](https://github.com/wladyband/apiAlternativo-ui-estatico/tree/master/brewer-ui/src/app/cidades)

Beleza mas quando fui adaptar-lo para pega dados da minha API Java não tive sucesso, é essa mensagem de erro que está dando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu componente ficou assim;

```
import { Estado, Cidade } from './../../core/model';
import { CidadesService } from './../cidades.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cidades-pesquisa',
  templateUrl: './cidades-pesquisa.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cidades-pesquisa.component.css']
})
export class CidadesPesquisaComponent implements OnInit {


 codigo: string;
 cidadePorEstado: string;

  estados = new Estado();
  cidades = new Cidade();

   constructor(
     private cidadesService: CidadesService
     ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.cidadesService
    .buscarEstados()
    .subscribe(result => this.estados = result);


    this.pesquisarCidades();
    this.pesquisarEstado();

  }


  pesquisarCidades() {
    this.cidadesService.listarTodasCidades()
    .then(() => null);
  }

  pesquisarEstado() {
    this.cidadesService.listarTodosEstados()
    .then(() => null);
  }


buscarCidades() {
    this.cidadesService.buscarCidadePorUF(
      this.codigo)
      .subscribe(result => this.cidades = result);
  }


}
```

O serviço ficou assim:

```
import { Cidade, Estado } from './../core/model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, URLSearchParams, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class CidadesService {

  cidadesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/cidades';
  estadosUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/cidades/estados';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  listarTodasCidades(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.cidadesUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json());
  }

  listarTodosEstados(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.estadosUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json());
  }



  buscarEstados(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of([
      this.listarTodosEstados()
     ]);
  }

  buscarCidadePorUF(codigo: string): Observable<any> {
    if (codigo === 'codigo_estado') {
      return Observable.of([
       this.listarTodasCidades()
      ]);
    } else {

    return Observable.of([ ]);
    }
  }

}
```

E minha pagina ficou assim;

```
<div class="container">
  <select name="estado" id="estado" [(ngModel)]="codigo" (change)="buscarCidades()">
    <option *ngFor="let estado of estados" [value]="estado.codigo">{{estado.nome}}</option>
  </select>

  <select name="cidade" id="cidade" [(ngModel)]="cidadePorEstado">
    <option *ngFor="let cidade of cidades" [value]="cidade.cidadePorEstado">{{cidade.nome}}</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br> UF Selecionada: {{codigo}}

  <br>
  <br> IBGE Selecionado: {{cidadePorEstado}}
</div>
```

Eu fiz uns teste e minha API Angular está conseguindo o GET do estado e das cidades veja;

```
  listarTodasCidades(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.cidadesUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.json());
      });
  }
```

Ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E de Estados:

```
  listarTodosEstados(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.estadosUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.json());
      });
  }
```

ficou assim;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebe que ele está chamando duas vezes;

O meu repositório está assim, [Clique aqui](https://github.com/wladyband/apiAlternativo-ui/tree/master/brewer-ui/src/app/cidades)

Não sei como resolver esse problema, aceito sugestões;

Meu banco de dados ficou assim:

cidades

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

============ATUALIZAÇÃO=======================

Fui orientado a fazer as seguintes modificações;

O componente:

```
import { Estado, Cidade } from './../../core/model';
import { CidadesService } from './../cidades.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-cidades-pesquisa',
  templateUrl: './cidades-pesquisa.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cidades-pesquisa.component.css']

})
export class CidadesPesquisaComponent implements OnInit {


  codigo: string;
  cidadePorEstado: string;

  estados: Estado[] = [];
  cidades: Cidade[] = [];

  constructor(
    private cidadesService: CidadesService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    // Aqui vc só precisa chamar a consulta de estados para carregar o select de estado e
    // a pesquisa de cidade só deve ocorrer no change do select de estado
    this.cidadesService
      .buscarEstados()
      .subscribe(result => this.estados = result);


    // então esses dois métodos não existe
    // this.pesquisarCidades();
    // this.pesquisarEstado();

  }


  /*

  Não precisa desses métodos
  pesquisarCidades() {
    this.cidadesService.listarTodasCidades()
      .then(() => null);
  }

  pesquisarEstado() {
    this.cidadesService.listarTodosEstados()
      .then(() => null);
  }*/


  buscarCidades() {
    this.cidadesService.buscarCidadePorUF(this.codigo)
      .subscribe(result => this.cidades = result);
  }


}
```

O serviço;

```
import { Cidade, Estado } from './../core/model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, URLSearchParams, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class CidadesService {

  cidadesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/cidades';
  estadosUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/cidades/estados';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  buscarEstados(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.estadosUrl);
  }

  buscarCidadePorUF(codigo: string): Observable<any> {
    // Aqui seu endpoint tem que receber o parâmetro codigo do estado e já retornar filtrado, ficaria assim:
    return this.http.get(`${this.cidadesUrl}&codigoEstado=${codigo}`);


    // Agora cara seu endpoint não estiver preparado para filtrar as cidades por estado vc usa o código abaixo e la no seu componente de cidades-pesquisa vc tem que filtrar por estado;
    //return this.http.get(this.cidadesUrl);
  }

}
```

**Estou enfrentando o seguinte erro:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja mais detalhe:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então descobrir que meu problema erra esse:

[EXCEPTION: Response with status: 200 Ok for URL:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839568/exception-response-with-status-200-ok-for-url)

Então encontrei esse site para resolver meu problema:

[How to use Angular 2 JSONP](https://medium.com/@FanggengYang/how-to-use-angular-2-jsonp-c75460ad614c)

Por causa disso resolvi instalar-lo com o comando abaixo;

```
  npm install jsonp
```

Veja o código antes:

```
import { Cidade, Estado } from './../core/model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, URLSearchParams, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class CidadesService {

  cidadesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/cidades';
  estadosUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/cidades/estados';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  buscarEstados(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.estadosUrl);
  }

  buscarCidadePorUF(codigo: string): Observable<any> {
    // Aqui seu endpoint tem que receber o parâmetro codigo do estado e já retornar filtrado, ficaria assim:
    return this.http.get(`${this.cidadesUrl}&codigoEstado=${codigo}`);


    // Agora cara seu endpoint não estiver preparado para filtrar as cidades por estado vc usa o código abaixo e la no seu componente de cidades-pesquisa vc tem que filtrar por estado;
    //return this.http.get(this.cidadesUrl);
  }

}
```

E o código depois da modificação:

```
import { Cidade, Estado } from './../core/model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, URLSearchParams, Headers, Jsonp } from '@angular/http';// modificação foi aqui!
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class CidadesService {

  cidadesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/cidades';
  estadosUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/cidades/estados';

  constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp) { }// modificação foi aqui!

  buscarEstados(): Observable<any> {
    return this.jsonp.get(this.estadosUrl);// modificação foi aqui!
  }

  buscarCidadePorUF(codigo: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.jsonp.get(`${this.cidadesUrl}&codigoEstado=${codigo}`); // modificação foi aqui!


  }

}
```

Ai ele gerou esse outro erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo que eu entendi, posso está enganado, ele quer que eu mude de `HttpModule` para `JsonpModule`, mas se eu fizer isso vou ter que alterar o meu projeto todo que usar **HttpModule**, é meio complicado porque meu projeto está um pouco grande.

Comment: Estou fazendo um curso de Angular-4 e estou no serviço `HTTP`, eu poderia tentar te ajudar caso você diminuísse sua pergunta e tentasse focar no problema em si.

Comment: eu estou usando vscode

Comment: Olha pelo pouco que aprendi nesse curso: [Construindo Aplicações Web Com o Novo Angular 4](https://www.udemy.com/angular-pt/learn/v4/) usei somente um `modulo`(que é bootstrap da minha aplicação)e você está usando vários módulos(não cheguei nessa parte ainda). Minha opinião  *(não sei se é a correta)* no lugar dos seus módulos deveria ser componentes. O legal de você fazer o curso que além do professor explicar bem ele te mostra como verificar erros a cada modificação no código, que aliás o seu está cheio. Sinceramente eu recomendo você descartar tudo e refazer, não exite em discordar!

Comment: O fato de ter vários modulos é porque estou com um projeto bastante evoluído e a organização do meu projeto está seguindo uma boa pratica de programação em relação a organização do projeto, como não poderia colocar o projeto completo porque poderia confundir a pessoa que pudesse me ajudar resolver somente colocar uma parte do meu projeto na pastagem, eu sou grato em me mostra uma boa referencia de curso mas infelizmente não tenho dinheiro para fazer o curso, eu reconheço que é um bom curso, se eu pudesse eu realmente fária, mas não estou em condições financeiras de fazer o curso.